# Solving Geodesics

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics

I'm wondering how to solve the geodesic equation to get a null geodesic. I know the two equations

$$\frac{d^2x^\mu}{ds^2}+{\Gamma^\mu}_{\nu\lambda}\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}\frac{dx^\lambda}{ds}=0$$

and the null one

$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{ds}\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}=0,$$

but how do you do this, given a metric? Consider, for example,

$$ds^2=\cos\sigma\,d\tau^2+d\sigma^2.$$

I don't understand how to plug this in and actually find the null geodesics once I've calculated the Christoffel symbols. thanks!

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for all math.

Comment: How much experience do you have solving coupled nonlinear differential equations?

Comment: i have done some in the past, and i'm sure I can figure it out in general, i'm just generally confused on what this 's' is denoting when taking the derivatives, and overall what the equation should look like plugged in.

Comment: Do you understand what a parameterized curve is? $s$ parameterizes the geodesic. When the geodesic is timelike instead of null, it’s the proper time along the geodesic.

Comment: Hm. I think that's part of where i'm getting confused. so does s parametrizing it mean that you can see what the curve does at a specific time? would i then just have to leave things in terms of ds, or how would I get that to work into my equation?

Comment: Your coordinates on the manifold are $\sigma$ and $\tau$. You solve the differential equations to find two functions, $\sigma(s)$ and $\tau(s)$, that represent a parameterized curve on this manifold. Each value of $s$ identifies one point on the curve. It’s analogous to finding $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ for the trajectory of a projectile.

Comment: Oh, I see, that explains so much, thank you! a hint i was given on my assignment (not the metric above, but somewhat similar), was that to solve the 2nd order DE we can set dσ/dλ = f(σ) - do you happen to know where the λ comes into play here?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand that hint.

Comment: that's alright! I also have another quick question, sorry- so i can plug in my Γs and what i have for a,b, and c, but then with the second equation, the one that makes it null, you have derivatives of a and b rather than of b and c, which are in the first equation. how would you plug in this equation into the main one to get the answer? or would you set them equal to each other?

Comment: What do you “have for a, b, and c”?

Comment: so one of my Γs is Γ(t,tσ) which equals -cotσ in my case. so a=t, b=t, and c=σ, for example? i assume i just do the same for all of my Γs and get a few different equations once i figure out how to make the equation?

Comment: *you have derivatives of a and b rather than of b and c* I think you are confused about a, b, and c. They are just *indices* identifying one if the coordinates. The indices can’t be differentiated; the coordinates get differentiated. You have probably gotten confused by letting them the values $\tau$ and $\sigma$ rather than 1 and 2.

Comment: hm, okay- so what then can I really plug in and how could i make the geodesic equation, if the only thing I have is the Γ with the various indices?

Comment: I have an errand to run, and can’t continue our discussion. It sounds like you may not yet understand free indices, contracted indices, Einstein summation convention, etc. I will check back later, but comments are not an appropriate place to learn index notation.

Comment: your example metric is positive definite and has no null geodesics.

Answer (score 0):

Following Ray D'Inverno. Introducing Einstein's Relativity. Page 101.

Assuming u is an affine parameter.

If $2K\equiv g_{ab}\dot{x}^a\dot{x}^b =\dot{x}^a\dot{x}_a $ then you can quickly read off $\Gamma^a _{bc}$ from the geodesic equation in the form

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial x^a } - \frac{d}{du} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{x}^a})=0$ where $2K=\text{C}=0,+1,-1$.

---

Example:

$ds^2 = \eta^2 d\tau^2 - d\eta^2 \to K=\frac{1}{2}(\eta^2 \dot\tau^2 - \dot{\eta}^2 ) $

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial x^a } - \frac{d}{ds} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{x}^a})=0 \to \frac{\partial K}{\partial \tau } - \frac{d}{ds} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{\tau}})=0\to2\eta \dot{\eta}\dot{\tau}+\eta^2 \ddot{\tau}=0\to$

$\ddot{\tau}+\frac{2}{\eta} \dot{\eta} \dot{\tau}=0\implies\Gamma^\tau _{\eta \tau}=\frac{2}{\eta}=\Gamma^\tau _{\tau\eta}$

---

$ds^2=\cos σ dτ^2+ dσ^2$

$\to$

$K=\cos σ {\dot{τ}}^2+ {\dot{σ}}^2 =0$

$\to$

$\cos(\sigma){\dot{τ}}^2 = - {\dot{σ}}^2 $

That's one differential equation.

Next calculate,

$\frac{\partial K}{\partial x^a } - \frac{d}{du} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{x}^a})=0$

$\to$

$ \frac{d}{du} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{\tau}})=0$

$ \frac{d}{du} (\frac{\partial K}{\partial \dot{\sigma}})=0$

$\to$

$\frac{\partial (\cos(σ) {\dot{τ}})}{\partial u}=0$

$\to$

$ -\sin(σ) \dot{\sigma} \dot{τ} + cos(\sigma) \ddot{\tau}=0$

and

$\ddot{\sigma}=0$.

---

$\cos(\sigma){\dot{τ}}^2 = - {\dot{σ}}^2 $

$ -\sin(σ) \dot{\sigma} \dot{τ} + cos(\sigma) \ddot{\tau}=0$

$\ddot{\sigma}=0$.

$\to$

$\sigma(u)=\frac{a}{2} u^2 +bu +c$

$\to$

$\dot{\sigma}(u)= au +b $

$\to$

$\dot{\tau}^2 = \frac{-(u+b)^2}{cos(\frac{1}{2} au^2 +ub +c)}$

set $b=c=0$ and $a=2$

$\to$

$\dot{\tau}^2 = \frac{-(u)^2}{cos(u^2)}$

etc. etc... ?